# jQuery show() function is not working

Tags: jquery

When I click 'edit' button I want 'info' div to be visible. It's working when I tried with javascript dom manipulation. I wanted to do the same with jQuery.
Here is my [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/priyaa2002/Xt4gN/).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button#edit').click(function() {
         $('.col2-content#info').show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you were loading mootools instead of jQuery, but see here revised. Note changes to selectors to just be by ID as well, you don't need such complicated selectors.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/PWYhD/

Comment: <loading mootools instead of jQuery> can you please explain..I'm just calling jQuery ready(function()).

Comment: @dragonfly He means in fiddle you selected mootols instead of jquery.